# Prove that a set of nonzero real numbers is a group under the operation $a*b$

Tags: group-theory

prove that the set of nonzero numbers is a group under the operation $*$ defined by $a*b = \{ab \text{ if } a > 0 \text{ or } \frac{a}{b} \text{ if } a < 0\}$. Show that it proves **closure, identity, inverses** and associative properties of a group.

Comment: Closure: Pick $a,b \in R$, then is $a*b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for :http://math.stackexchange.com/q/658168

Comment: the Hungerford, 2nd ed. exercise 22 is just the associative - I am having trouble with all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you say you've tried closure and associative property is proved in the linked question.

$ \exists x \in \mathbb{R}$
That is, find an $e$ such that$ e \cdot a= a \cdot e= a$ holds. (and this happens to be $1$)

For inverses, we have that for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$ , $\exists a^{-1}$ such that $a \cdot a^{-1}= e$ holds.
(it does, and I hope you believe this).

**Found this after I answered.

[image]